# Multiple fields with the same name in Habitat

Tags: templates, habitat

In Habitat, I defined two templates: `_idenity` and `_footer`, and each of them has the same field name but different ID values,for example IDA and IDB.

The start root item inherits both these templates.

So when I use `item.Field(IDA)` or `item.Field(IDB)`, it always returns the same value. In my case, the field in the `_identity` template.

When I look deeply in code, the implementation is:

```
var field = item.Fields[fieldId];
FieldRenderer.Render(item, field.Name)
```

That means it will get value by name instead of by ID.

Is it possible to get value by ID?

Thanks,
Ton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to get value by ID? - **Yes**

Below is the code to get Sitecore Item Field Value by ID:

```
var fieldValue= item.InnerData.Fields[new ID(fieldId)];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an improper implementation in Habitat's [FieldRendererService](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/src/Foundation/SitecoreExtensions/code/Services/FieldRendererService.cs). And another reason why you shouldn't start a new (real) project based on that source code. It's really meant as a demo.

You can pass a stringified ID to the `FieldRenderer.Render` method, which is what should have been done here:

```
public static string RenderField(Item item, ID fieldId)
{
    var field = item.Fields[fieldId];
    Assert.IsNotNull(field, "Field with id: " + fieldId + " is null on item " + item.Name);
    return FieldRenderer.Render(item, fieldId.ToString());
}
```

I would also argue that it's a bit strange that the "field ID" variant checks for the field's existence, whereas the name-based variant does not. If you don't do this check, then Sitecore will silently return an empty string if the field doesn't exist.